# Hooking Up Visual Studio Team Project to Azure New Portal Only Showing GIT Projects

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I am a bit baffled
In the old Azure portal I was able to hook up my TFVC project on VSTS for continuous deployment. Today I tried to hook up a new project to find that Azure is only listing my GIT based team projects. How do I get at TFVC projects now?

my workflow is as follows
AppServices, select site > Options > Continuous Deployment > Choose Source, Visual Studio Team Services > Choose Account, My Account, Choose Project, *Only GITs are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this link for the Azure configuration with TFVC: [Continuous delivery to Azure using Visual Studio Team Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/)

Comment: Whoa, I looked at that tutorial all day, it was not until now that I realized the links on the body 'Azure Classic Portal' took you to the very easy to understand and intuitive classic portal where I now know what I am doing :)

Comment: Here is another article that might be a bit easier https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/aspnet4

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but currently this appears to be by design.
On the Kudu wiki which handles continuous deployments for webapps for azure - one of the troubleshooting steps is:

Is your project a git project? We only support linking with VSTS git project.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Setting-up-a-VSTS-account-so-it-can-deploy-to-a-Web-App

An option to accomplish the same goal is to create a Release in VSTS that publishes to the App service. It is really simple because it can automatically pull down the Subscription and apps from Azure to configure it.